# Puppeteer isn't compatible with Babel transform

Tags: headless-browser

I'm working with Puppeteer with Express JS project and use Babel to transform source code.
The problem is puppeteer is not compatible with Babel: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1665#issuecomment-354241717

```
await page.evaluate(`(async() => { echarts.getDataURL(); })()`);
```

It seems there is no way to get this code work properly.
Anyone has experience with other Headless library which run perfectly with Babel transformation?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to run this?